# Firebase Database only loading strings

Tags: swift, string, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am successful when loading the ID of the players, but when I use that ID to load the pictures, it fails.  So, the func loadPlayers works, and the func getPictures does not.  I don't know why, I've done this is other projects and it's worked.  Any help is appreciated!

```
 func loadPlayers () {
    ref = Database.database().reference()
    ref.child("Users/\(playerIDentered)").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

        let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
        USfighter1.ID = value?["fighter1ID"] as! Int
        USfighter2.ID = value?["fighter2ID"] as! Int
        USfighter3.ID = value?["fighter3ID"] as! Int
        USfighter4.ID = value?["fighter4ID"] as! Int
        USfighter5.ID = value?["fighter5ID"] as! Int
        USfighter6.ID = value?["fighter6ID"] as! Int
        USfighter7.ID = value?["fighter7ID"] as! Int
        USfighter8.ID = value?["fighter8ID"] as! Int
        USfighter9.ID = value?["fighter9ID"] as! Int
        USfighter10.ID = value?["fighter10ID"] as! Int
        USfighter11.ID = value?["fighter11ID"] as! Int
        USfighter12.ID = value?["fighter12ID"] as! Int
        USfighter13.ID = value?["fighter13ID"] as! Int
        USfighter14.ID = value?["fighter14ID"] as! Int
        USfighter15.ID = value?["fighter15ID"] as! Int
        USfighter16.ID = value?["fighter16ID"] as! Int

    }) { (error) in
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }

}

func getPictures () {
    //ref = Database.database().reference()
    ref.child("\(USfighter1.ID)").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

        let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
        USfighter1.Picture = value?["Picture"] as? String ?? ""
        self.fighter1.texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "\(USfighter1.Picture)")

    }) { (error) in
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
```

Here is the database structure as well.

```
 {
   "1" : {
     "Fname" : "Sunny",
     "Lname" : "Liston",
     "Picture" : "90-SunnyListon"
   },
   "2" : {
     "Fname" : "Rocky",
     "Lname" : "Marciano",
     "Picture" : "94-RockyMarciano"
   },
   "Fighters" : [ null, {
     "Fname" : "Sunny",
     "Lname" : "Liston",
     "Picture" : "90-SunnyListon"
   }, {
     "Fname" : "Rocky",
     "Lname" : "Marciano",
     "Picture" : "94-RockyMarciano"
   } ],
   "Users" : [ null, {
     "Coins" : 10000000,
     "fighter10ID" : 0,
     "fighter11ID" : 0,
     "fighter12ID" : 0,
     "fighter13ID" : 0,
     "fighter14ID" : 0,
     "fighter15ID" : 0,
     "fighter16ID" : 0,
     "fighter1ID" : 2,
     "fighter2ID" : 1,
     "fighter3ID" : 0,
     "fighter4ID" : 0,
     "fighter5ID" : 0,
     "fighter6ID" : 0,
     "fighter7ID" : 0,
     "fighter8ID" : 0,
     "fighter9ID" : 0
   } ]
 }
```

Comment: which bit is not working? is 'USfighter1.ID' set correctly? does 'USfighter1.Picture' return the correct text?  Also, you're confusing the question a bit here  - all you're trying to load from the database is strings - USFighter1.Picture is a string describing an image, not an image

Comment: You are correct.  I am simply trying to load a string.  The USfighter1.Picture is not returning the proper string.  This is odd because USfighter1.ID is. @Russell

Comment: Your fighter key in the database is a string, but you convert it to an Int, and then back again.  What happens if you load the key as a string, and use it that way?

Comment: That seems to be what I am trying to do.  Do you think your can help me do that?  Or did you mean the ID?  I could try that I suppose.  @Russell

Comment: I can help sort it - we can use the chat rooms, but not for an hour or two

Comment: Ok.  But why is this different then when I have done this in the past.  I am simply trying to load the USfighter1.Picture string, is it because I am loading it from a variable path? @Russell

Comment: Alright.  I figured out the problem.  It was working, it just didn't load the ID's before it went to the getPictures function.  Is there anyway that I wait to go to that function until after they are loaded?

Comment: Easy.  Just make the call from within the completion handler of the first call - so just after you assign the IDs you call self.getPictures()

Comment: Great.  That did it, thanks @Russell.

Comment: Cool.  Good luck with the rest of the project